# cannot transfer binary files to mbed controller NXP LPC1768 connected via USB

Tags: 14.04

I have version 14.04 LTS and Windows vista on an ACER aspire

I compile and download a binary file from the mbed site. Then file must be transferred to the controller connected by USB (by copy , move to , or cut  )

The operation fails and the following error appears 
"error opening "file name" read only file system "

With Windows there is no problem .

Thank you
Markos

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of command `mount | grep ^/` please?

Comment: Why do you still have Vista?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an ARCH GPRS V2, which has NXP LPC11U37 Controller. It would copy new firmware on Windows but not Ubuntu.

By running `dd if={new_firmware.bin} of={mnt_dir}/firmware.bin conv=notrunc` I got it working. I found that the `notrunc` flag is crucial.